# teradata sql find average value of specified column names

Tags: sql, teradata

In Teradata database, named teradatadb.. I have 2 tables for example..

For table 1, table name: tb1, contains following columns: 
tb1_acc, tb1_mn, tb1_dly, tb1_yr, tb_acc, xxx_acc

For table 2, table name: tb2, contains following columns: 
tb2_acc, tb2_mn, tb2_dly, tb2_yr, tbx_acc, ccc_acc

Each column has a lot of different numeric values..

Now I would like to find out the column in the teradatadb contains keyword 'acc' and give out the average of this column.. Pls advise how to write the sql code.

Following are my codes to find the columns..

```
    select DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName
    from dbc.columns 
    where columnname like '%acc%'  and databasename = 'teradatadb'
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL, which in Teradata would typically use `execute immediate` (http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_109A/ch10.12.03.html).

Comment: Thanks~ could you please give out the code or an example? I have never dealt with dynamic sql before

Comment: . . To be honest, I haven't used dynamic SQL in Teradata.  I could give examples for Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, and Postgres.  There should be examples on the web.